# Take value from array and select it in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, video

I have problem that I store in DB column (video_id) and the value of it like that store (1,3,4,7) the number mean the id of video in the Video table which store the video title and text and all information about the video but when I wrote code to select all video the result give me one video

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <?
    $qu="SELECT video_id FROM `training_questions` WHERE id=$questions_id AND category_id=$training_id";
    $query_c=  mysqli_query($con, $qu);
    while ($row7 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_c)) {
        $vedoes=$row['video_id'];
        $pieces = explode(",", $vedoes);
    }
    for($i=0;$i<=count($pieces);$i++){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `video` WHERE id IN $pieces[$i] ";
        $query_che=  mysqli_query($con, $query);
        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_che)) {  ?>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="video-container">
                        <div class="thumb"> <a href="video_details.php?id=<?= $row2['id'] ?>"> <img src="../upload/<?= $row2['img'] ?>" class="img-responsive img-rounded media-preview" alt=""> <span class="zoom-image"><i class="icon-play3"></i></span> </a> </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h6 class="no-margin">
                            <a href ="video_details.php?id=<?= $row2['id'] ?>" class="text-default"><?= $row2['title'] ?>
                            </a>
                        </h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <? 
        }
    } ?>
</div>
```

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
$pieces = explode(",", $vedoes);
```

its useless

make your for loop condition look like this

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($vedoes);$i++)
```

Hope it Helps